# What would be the best way of making this piece of code smaller?

Tags: java, field, label

I was wondering if we are adding the same components to java (in the main class)over and over again and writing separate code for each of them, would it be possible to make the code smaller? e.g. if we are adding buttons and labels many times, which each do different job, would it it possible to have them in less code or does it have to be like that e.g.

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Text1");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label);
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field);


    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Text2");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label1);
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field1);
    field1.setEnabled(false);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Text3");
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label2);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field2);

field2.setEnabled(false);
```

In my code I have to add the same components over and over again like 10 times but each one is doing a different job, would it be possible to have them in less code?

Also I want to be able to store the values of each textbox in a different variable, e.g. store the value of field1 to int number;.

Comment: what about creating a method for that??? I don't see that difference

Comment: A would use an array and make a method for creating components.

Comment: 1.Create ArrayList<JLabel>   
2.Create method for adding JLabel to arraylist   
3.Make it take a String name parameter   
4.Profit???

Comment: iberbeu is correct, create a method and pass your JLabel object, panel object and a boolean for whether it is enabled or not.  This would reduce this code block to three lines.

Comment: @tintinmj the array is only required if the Labels are really going to be used later, if not the simple method is enough

Comment: could you please show me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that you can reuse:

```
private void method createLabel(JPanel panel, String text) {
     JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
     label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
     panel.add(label);
     JTextField field = new JTextField();
     panel.add(field);
}
```

If you need extra things like `setEnabled()` or whatever, just pass parameters in order to do it or not depending on requirements. If you need the Labels back just change `void` to `JLabel` and return it. Then you call it like this

```
createLabel(panel, "text1");
createLabel(panel, "text2");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create ArrayList
2.Create method for adding JLabel to arraylist 
3.Make it take a String name parameter 
4.Profit???

Answer (score 0):

> "would it be possible to make the code smaller? "

Yes. One way, as @iberbue suggested is to use a method. You can have a method that return a `JPanel` and pass arguments to it

Have a look at this example I was working on for a different question. But it serves the same purpose. Look at the method `createPanel` that return a `JPanel`. Then I just use `JPanel panel = createPanel(...)`;

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test2 {

    Map<String, JTextField> fields;
    Map<String, JLabel> labels;

    public Test2() {
        fields = new HashMap<>();
        labels = new HashMap<>();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            JPanel panel = createPanel("Text Field " + i);
            mainPanel.add(panel);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new Test2();
            }
        });
    }

    private JPanel createPanel(String fieldName) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        field.addActionListener(new FieldListener());
        fields.put(fieldName, field);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(fieldName);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        labels.put(fieldName, label);

        JButton button = new JButton(fieldName);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
            String fieldName = button.getText();
            JTextField field = fields.get(fieldName);
            System.out.println(field.getText());
        }
    }

    public class FieldListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTextField field = (JTextField)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(field.getText());
        }
    }

    public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
            System.out.println(label.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method, something like this.

```
private void add(JPanel panel, int i, boolean enabled){
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Text" + i);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label);
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field);
    field.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```

And then you call it 3 times as needed.

Comment: hi, each label will have different text and also each field will have different value which i will need to get later on.

Answer (score 0):

You've noticed that most code is repeated. This is a good first step.

Then, notice what parts change (semantically) between iterations (that is, ignore the different variable names and other unimportant info): `new JLabel(theLabelThatChanges)`and `.setEnabled(thisFieldEnabled)`.

Then, put all these in a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(theLabelThatChanges);
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label2);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field2);
    field1.setEnabled(thisFieldEnabled);
}
```

Make sure have a collection of values for the thing that changes:

```
String[] labels = new String[] { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3" };
boolean[] enabledBoxes = new boolean { true, false, true };
```

Be sure to grab a value in each iteration:

```
String theLabelThatChanges = labels[i];
boolean thisFieldEnabled = enabledBoxes[i];
```

Final code:

```
String[] labels = new String[] { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3" };
boolean[] enabledBoxes = new boolean { true, false, true };
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    String theLabelThatChanges = labels[i];
    boolean thisFieldEnabled = enabledBoxes[i];

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(theLabelThatChanges);
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label2);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field2);
    field1.setEnabled(thisFieldEnabled);
}
```

As others have commented, you could then take the part that creates all this stuff and make it a separate procedure that takes the label and the enabled status as parameters:

```
private void addControls(String theLabelThatChanges, boolean thisFieldEnabled)
{
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(theLabelThatChanges);
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(label2);
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    panel.add(field2);
    field1.setEnabled(thisFieldEnabled);
}
```

Then call it from the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    addControls(labels[i], enabledBoxes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks theodoros, this is a good way of doing it, it will make my code a lot short. I have one question though, do each component have there own unique name which I can refer to. e.g. if i want to use the value of field to, or disable textfield1, how would i do that?

Comment: If you want to keep their references for future use, you'll have to add them to an array, at the end of the loop, like so: `myLabels[i] = label2;` and `myTextFields[i] = field2;`. These two arrays should be declared in the class, outside of the method.

Comment: Theodoros, so each label and field can be refered to as label1, label2, label3 and field1, field2, field3, so if i want to print the value of field2 or pass the value of field3 to another variable i would do something like system.out.println(field3); or int a = field3;

Comment: @Peter They can't be called `label1`, `label2`, anymore. But they *can* be called `myLabels[0]`, `myLabels[1]` and so on (or whatever you choose, but they'll still have square brackets). This is equivalent in all respects to what you want, except that you can iterate over them using a loop (thus minimizing the printing code too).

Comment: Java was no sense of the fact that `label3` "comes after" `label2`, since variable names are arbitrary. But Java *does* (sort of) have a sense of the fact that `myLabels[3]` "comes after" `myLabels[2]` (because the number here has a special meaning as an *index*, not just part of an arbitrary variable name) and you can use this fact to your advantage.

Comment: So how would I refer to each of the labels and each of the textfield, for example if I want print the value of label2 or get the value of textfield2.

Comment: `myTextFields[0].setEnabled(false)` will disable the *first* text field. Similarly, `System.out.println(myLabels[1].getText())` will print the *second* label's text, and so on.

Comment: How can I get the value of the JFields?

Comment: `myTextField[0].getText()` should return the text of the first field, in this case.

Comment: Theodoros, where did u get myTextField[0] from?

Comment: As I said, you'll have to declare and initialize it in the class: `JTextField[] myTextFields = new JTextField[10];`.

Comment: which class do i need to declare it in?

Comment: Same class as the method that you posted in your question is. Similarly for the labels.

Comment: what do the [10] mean?

Comment: It's the number of slots in the array. It can store up to 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Complexer answer.
If you want to be OO.

Make class CustomJButton extends JButton

Set Everything you need in the contructor

You will be able to do this if you're not going to use the Button vars anymore

```
    new CustomJButton("NAME");
```

You will be able to do this if you're going to use the Button vars

```
    CustomJButton j = new CustomJButton("NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought there already should be some **fluent swing GUI API**, but I did not find any on the spur. JavaFX GUI on Java 8 is nice.

Though Java 8 allows terse event listeners with Java 7 one can do a fluent API too.

```
JPanel panel = new FrameBuilder().panel()
    .children()
        .label("Text1")
            .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER)
        .textField()
            .setId("field1")
        .label("Text2")
            .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER)
        .textField()
            .setId("field2")
            .setEnabled(false)
    .endChildren()
    .create();
```

Where FrameBuilder.panel gives a PanelBuilder whose create returns the JPanel. Or so.